# Facebook SDK title, description, caption and image fields are deprecated

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

**Upgrading the Android SDK from 4.21.1 to 4.22.0**

*Facebook SDK
The title, description, caption and image field of FBSDKShareLinkContent have been deprecated. Please take appropriate action to remove usage of them.*

How to set Content title and description now? Can anyone suggest something to make it work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The facebook crawler will extract that from the URL you're using in the ShareLinkContent.

Comment: Thanks @Aiapaec for the solution. But What I want to do is to share the content from my android application on button click event and that too with dynamic values from my model. 
So any code snippet or hint that how can I achieve it will be thankful.

Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the [Android-Sharing facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) says:

> When you implement sharing, your app should not pre-fill any content
>   to be shared. This is inconsistent with Facebook Platform Policy, see
>   [Facebook Platform Policy, 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control).

From Facebook Platform Policy

> 3. Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person or business didn’t create,
>      even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing. You
>      may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but
>      don't prefill any content a person or business didn't create via the
>      API.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
What I did is I just made an html page and passed the values in meta tag for the attributes "content", "description" and "title" dynamically and gave the url of html page in shareLinkContent > SetContentUrl method.
So when shared it automatically picked the values from that html page.
This Worked in my case.

Happy Coding..!